# Couldn't find an installed template that matches the input [creating .netcore webAPI project from CLI] --

Tags: c#, .net, command-line-interface, asp.net-core-webapi

Just a quick query here.
Trying to create a new .NETCORE webAPI project from command line.

Used:  **dotnet new webapi RequisitionAPI -n**

doesn't work. I get the error

```
    Couldn't find an installed template that matches the input, searching online for one that does...

    Invalid input switch:
    RequisitionAPI
    ASP.NET Core Web API (C#)
    Author: Microsoft
    Description: A project template for creating an ASP.NET Core application with an example   Controller for a RESTful HTTP service. This template can also be used for ASP.NET Core MVC Views and Controllers.
```

what's wrong here. That's how it is depicted in the docs. Don't understand why it says that it can't find a installed template. .NET Sdk is well installed. Version 3.1.405.

Pipe me on this quickly please. what's the glitch??

Comment: "That's how it is depicted in the docs" -> which docs are those? Can you point us to them?

Comment: "That's how it is depicted in the docs -> which docs are those? Can you point us to them?"       @omajid            https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/tools/dotnet-new

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to define the option -n before RequisitionAPI:

```
dotnet new webapi -n RequisitionAPI
```